# Play2.0 returns "SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection."

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, bonecp

I have been using Play 2.0.2 in order to create a Java application. For a few days I'm running into a problem. After ~100 request the server starts to throw this exception:

> [[SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.]]

I create a new instance of `Connection` with `DB.getConnection()`. I don't close the `Connection` instances because there's only one instance of each request and as far as I know it automatically closes `Connection` instances when the active TCP connection is closed.
I tried to increase `db.default.connectionTimeout` value to `100 seconds` but it couldn't fix the problem. Then I checked active Postgresql connections and there was no active connection. Also I restarted Postgresql but it also couldn't fix the problem.

The only solution for this problem for now is killing the Play20 instance and starting a new one.

Here is the log Play2.0 created:

```
! @6cg9il6ki - Internal server error, for request [GET [AN URL]] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.]]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:503) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:114) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
        at play.api.db.DBApi$class.getConnection(DB.scala:64) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.getConnection(DB.scala:273) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.api.db.DB$$anonfun$getConnection$1.apply(DB.scala:129) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.api.db.DB$$anonfun$getConnection$1.apply(DB.scala:129) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
```

Comment: AFAIK, you have to close the connection after use (in a `finally` block for instance)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275102/sqlexception-timed-out-waiting-for-a-free-available-connection/28395713#28395713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that:

> I don't close the Connection instances because there's only one
>   instance of each request

That's wrong, you have to close it otherwise you end up with the issue you see.

The reason is that you are getting a direct JDBC connection, not one managed by the ORM (EBeans or some other JPA-compliant) so if you don't close it the connection may be dangling for a while.

Comment: @hi Pere Villega I have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527954/play-framework-2-2-error-this-exception-has-been-logged-with-id  Can you please resolve this.. I am using an ORM and still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use DB.withConnection, it closes the connection once its done.

Comment: It seems DB.withConnection is only available for Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Play framework Java implementation for database should be something like this.

```
try{
      Ebean.beginTransaction();

      // your code goes here
      // if all things go fine 
       Ebean.commitTransaction();


}catch (Exception e){
      //got error so log it.
      e.printStackTrace();

}finally{
      //End the transactions started
      Ebean.endTransaction();
}
```