# SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm building an app in java with `Play Framework 2.0.4`. The app is deployed in `heroku` with cleardb database.

Users keep getting this occasional error:

```
PlayException: Execution exception [[PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:516)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.TransactionManager.createQueryTransaction(TransactionManager.java:356)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQueryTransaction(DefaultServer.java:2021)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.initTransIfRequired(OrmQueryRequest.java:241)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findId(DefaultServer.java:1212)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.java:1118)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.java:1105)
    at play.db.ebean.Model$Finder.byId(Model.java:237)
```

Now is getting worse and sometimes all users get the same error every time until I restart the app in heroku.

Any help or tips to debug it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the same of [Heroku/Play/BoneCp connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480506/heroku-play-bonecp-connection-issues/15500442#15500442)

Heroku close the connections after 30 seconds.

Comment: With boneCP 0.8.0.rc2 and indicated boneCP config parameters the issue doesn't occur since yesterday

Answer (score 2):

After adding boneCp 0.8.0.rc1, on Build.scala and

```
db.default.idleMaxAge=10 minutes
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30 seconds
db.default.connectionTimeout=20 second
db.default.connectionTestStatement="SELECT 1"
db.default.maxConnectionAge=30 minutes
```

but I still got the timeout error, specifically when i left the page opened and then hit refresh.

Comment: Upgraded to boneCP 0.8.0-rc2 problem remains

Comment: I'm in the process of changing my db to postgresql, and it seems that these errors disappeared. Although i'm still struggling with a postgresql db.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue.This issue occured when there is huge reuqest thread on your Play Application and play can't able to maintain DB pool.To make Play comfortable for maintaining DB pool  You need to add below three point in you aplliaction.conf files

- **db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=100** // this say what Max
  connection your Play Framework need ti maintain
- **db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=10** //During start minimum how
  many DB connection it should have
- **db.default.acquireIncrement=10** // Once Db connection exceed to
  maxConnectionsPerPartition then how much it need to assign more in
  pool

Answer (score 0):

Hi have this question too, have you managed to solve it?
I searched on the web, about this. 
They all say that you do not close your connections to the database. 
But I dont open them at all, I mean play do this for me. 
They also found the code close only works on scala..

The last "solution" I found, but it is not working 100%, is in the configuration file.
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsJDBC

Comment: I still have the same problem. It looks like boneCP 0.7.1 has some bugs. Fiddling with the parameters didn't solve it. Maybe you can try to upgrade boneCP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480506/heroku-play-bonecp-connection-issues